How does Stokes First Problem Yield the Error Function in its Solution?
When solving Stokes first problem using a similarity variable, I get to the point where I have converted the PDE (from Navier-Stokes Eqn) into an ODE, and when I go to solve it the solution does not look like the error function.
The ODE I get using $\eta$ as a similarity variable looks like:
$f'' + \frac{\eta}{2}f'=0$
where $f$ is a function of $\eta$ and $\eta = \frac{y}{\sqrt{\nu t}}$
When I solve, I use the characteristic equation:
$r^2 + \frac{\eta}{2}r=0$
And get roots of $0$ and $-\frac{\eta}{2}$, giving me a solution of:
$f(\eta) = A + Be^{-\frac{\eta^2}{2}}$
However, every video that I watch explaining the solution of Stoke's First Problem ends up with the error function as the solution from the ODE:
$f(\eta) = A + B\mathbf{erf}({\frac{\eta^2}{2}})$
My understanding is that the error function is:
$\int_0^x{e^{-t^2}dt}$
So then $\mathbf{erf}(\frac{\eta^2}{2})$ would yield $\int_0^\frac{\eta^2}{2}{e^{-t^2}dt}$
So it seems I should be integrating my $e^{-\frac{\eta^2}{2}}$ somewhere? I'm not sure what I'm missing. Am I not allowed to use the characteristic equation to get a solution in this instance?

No, you are not. You can only use the characteristic equation if the ODE is linear and has constant coefficients.

@Gonçalo Ah thank you! That explains why this was coming out wrong.
